# Using WaveSurfer.js v2 in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wavesurfer.js

I'm trying to use WaveSurfer.js(version 2) with React.
I know that for version 1 there was a library called react-wavesurfer, but I really want to do it with v2.
I'm already experienced with it, without React. So, I just made a component of mine.

As you can see in the code below, it all works perfectly, the WaveSurfer object is generated correctly in the `componentDidMount()` but then, all of sudden, in the `load()` method, there's an error I can't understand correctly.

This error is throwed after the `load()`, and after the error, it's logged in console "There it happens!" and the wave property of the state, as it should be.

[This is the error in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqzcb.png) and by itself it doesn't mean nothing. That's just an error without stack trace in a obfuscated function in react-error-overlay. The second error, DOMException, is directly caused by the first, and they everytime are throwed together.

[This is the row of the react-error-overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKwD6.png) that causes the error directly, in `/node_modules/react-error-overlay/index.js:1582`, but it's obfuscated.

```
// ... various imports

class Track extends Component {
    wavref = null;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        let id = this.props.id;

        this.state = {
            id: id,
            wave: null
        };
    }

    load() {
        console.log(this.state.wave, this.props.audio); // this.props.audio is the correct path, and should work correctly: "../../demo.wav".
        this.state.wave.load(this.props.audio);
        console.log("There it happens!", this.state.wave);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let generatedWave = WaveSurfer.create({
            container: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.waveref),
            waveColor: this.state.color,
            progressColor: this.state.progressColor,
            plugins: [
                RegionsPlugin.create({
                    dragSelection: {
                        slop: 5
                    }
                }),
                CursorPlugin.create({})
            ]
        });

        this.setState({
            wave: generatedWave,
        }, function() {
            this.load();
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div ref={(waveref) => this.waveref = waveref}></div>
        );
    }
}

export default Track;
```

Obviously, the `load()` method doesn't load/render the actual wave in the WaveSurfer canvas, and throws that error. I can't understand why, because it should just work normally and render the wave in the WaveSurfer canvas.

Does anyone of you know what can the error be?

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No! I'm sorry for the late reply :( I just abandoned this project

Comment: Me too ... thanks for the reply!